# How to get flycheck to do a syntax check immediately after opening a file?

Tags: flycheck, haskell-mode

I can't get *flycheck* to do its thing immediately after opening a file.
It will check/find errors if I *save* the file.
And it will check/find errors if I execute the `M-x flycheck-mode` command twice (i.e. - disabling then re-enabling flycheck mode).

I'm guessing there're some subtle timing issues between `add-hook`, `eval-after-load`, and `with-eval-after-load` that I don't fully understand?

The relevant (I think) lines from my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```
;; Global Flycheck
(global-flycheck-mode)

(setq flymake-no-changes-timeout nil)
(setq flymake-start-syntax-check-on-newline nil)
(setq flycheck-check-syntax-automatically '(save mode-enabled))

(add-hook 'literate-haskell-mode-hook
          '(lambda () (flycheck-select-checker 'haskell-stack-liquid)))
(add-hook 'literate-haskell-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pulling the following line out of my `(use-package dante ...)` S-expression and into the top level of my `init.el` file did the trick.

```
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook          'flycheck-mode)
```

Comment: It should work in your `use-package` declaration as well, try it under `:init`.

Answer (score 0):

The Flycheck documentation suggests enabling `global-flycheck-mode` with:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
```

If you're using `use-package`, I think you need to run it in `:config`, which is run after the package is loaded, whereas `:init` is run before.

```
(use-package flycheck
  :config (global-flycheck-mode))
```